# How can I get my pwd with os.getcwd() without it printing on the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

Can't seem to find a way to have the getcwd command to give me the directory without automaticlly printing it, any alternatives will do as well.

```
import os
>>> os.getcwd()
/Users/me/downloads/
```

Comment: The `getcwd()` method does not print the directory, it returns a string. As you are in the interactive interpreter, it shows the returned string content. But you can simply store the returned string in a variable like this: `cwd = os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value to one variable to prevent printing result

```
a = os.getcwd()
```